# change Access Permissions in Component Services > COM Security with script/api?

Tags: com, dcom

How do I go about changing the Access Permissions for the COM Security? I need to write new values to "Edit Limits..." and "Edit Default..."

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OLE MachineAccessPermissions, MachineLaunchPermissions, DefaultAccessPermissions, and DefaultLaunchpermissions, Reg_Binary values, as to how to change it that's what I'm looking for now is an easy api to change it.